# How can I make the background of an HTML5 page an image with a link?

Tags: html, css, image, url, background

I have been creating a webpage teaching about Mars, and I wanted to see if I could make the background of an HTML5 page an image instead of a boring white colour. I do want this with a link, so teaching with a .jpg will not be useful. Here is some code I have tried:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>My Webpage</title>
            <style>
                body {
                background: url(https://phys.org/news/2020-05-astrobiologists-mars-rover-life-detecting-equipment.html);
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            My text here...
        </body>
   </html>
```

I am not the most experienced programmer, as you can see from this, but any help (even if it is just a little) will be much appreciated. Thank you for your time and have a great rest of your day.

--

isharief

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the link to the jpg file in the src attribute instead of the html link, for this case,

```
<style>
                body {
                    background: url(https://scx1.b-cdn.net/csz/news/800/2020/astrobiologi.jpg);
                    background-repeat: no-repeat;
                    background-size: cover;
                    background-position: center;
                    height: 100vh;
                    width: 100vw;
                    overflow: hidden
                }
            </style>
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked well, but now there are multiple pictures that are filling up the screen. Is there a way to make just one of them do it? Again, thank you so much for your time.